# Finding argument of power of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z=\sqrt 3-i$ then I have to write $z^7$ in $a+ib$ form.
$z^7=2^7(cos({-7\pi\over 6})+i sin({-7\pi\over 6}))$.
What I don't understand is writing the argument of this. It should be in $-\pi<Argz\leq \pi$ ?
Then it can be written as $z^7=2^7(cos(-(\pi+{\pi\over 6}))+i sin(-(\pi+{\pi\over 6})))=2^7(-cos({\pi\over6})+isin({\pi\over6}))$.
Or since ${-7\pi\over 6}$ is measured in the clockwise direction and falls in the second quadrant like this,  [image]should it be 
$z^7=2^7(cos({5\pi\over 6})+i sin({5\pi\over 6}))$.
Can someone please let me know how to find the argument in these cases?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{5\pi}6-\left(\dfrac{-7\pi}6\right)=2\pi$$

We can choose any argument of the form $2m\pi+\dfrac{5\pi}6$ where $m$ is any integer

as $\cos\left(2m\pi+\dfrac{5\pi}6\right)+i\sin\left(2m\pi+\dfrac{5\pi}6\right)=\cos\dfrac{5\pi}6+i\sin\dfrac{5\pi}6$

Comment: but shouldn't this be expressed in terms of the principal argument?

Answer (score 0):

Let us first obtain the answer by direct computation (squarings, then division):

$$z=\sqrt3-i\to z^2=2-2\sqrt3 i\to z^4=-8-8\sqrt3 i\to z^8=-128+128\sqrt3 i\to \\z^7=-64\sqrt3+64i.$$

Now by the polar form,

$$z=2e^{-i\pi/6}$$

and

$$z^7=2^7e^{-i7\pi/6}=128\left(\cos\frac{7\pi}6-i\sin\frac{7\pi}6\right)=128\left(-\cos\frac{\pi}6+i\sin\frac{\pi}6\right)
\\=-64\sqrt3+64i.$$

Note that to compute the power, the argument need *not* be normalized to the principal value as you take the sine/cosine.

$$\cos\frac{7\pi}6-i\sin\frac{7\pi}6=\cos\left(-\frac{5\pi}6\right)-i\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}6\right).$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, does that mean $2^7(-cos({\pi\over6})+isin({\pi\over6}))$ or $ \cos\dfrac{5\pi}6+i\sin\dfrac{5\pi}6$ are both correct?

Comment: @sam_rox: try and compute them.

Comment: @user376343: nobody ever said that you cannot precede a cosine by a minus. Be more specific.

Comment: @user376343: you leave some ambiguity. $z^7=128\left(\cos\frac{7\pi}6-i\sin\frac{7\pi}6\right)$ is a perfectly valid expression. Saying the opposite is precisely what puzzles the OP.

Comment: @user376343: seriously, you didn't hear me.

Comment: @user376343 Why can't "The sign − cannot preced cosine or sine"?$\cos\frac{-7\pi}6=\cos\frac{7\pi}6$, since it is an even function. Then $\cos\frac{7\pi}6=cos(\pi+{\pi \over 6})$. Since $cos(\pi+{\pi \over 6})$ falls in the 3rd quadrant it is $-cos({\pi \over 6})$.

Comment: I didn't want to make you confused. In the trigonometric form are the signs before the sine and cosine positive. Once the power is found, and you are looking for the algebraic form, the signs can be applied as did Yves.